# Nothing Happens When Running Script in Spyder

Tags: python

I am running this code and oddly, nothing happens. There is no error nor does it freeze. It simply just runs the code without storing variables, nothing is printed out and it doesn't open the window that is supposed to show the plot. So it simply does nothing. It is very odd. This worked only a few minutes ago and I did not change anything about it previously. I did make sure that the variable explorer is displaying all the definitions in the script. I intentionally removed the plotting section at the end since it just made the code set longer and the same issue persists here without it.

Code:

```
#Import libraries
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
#from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from time import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import grid
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy, scipy.io
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
'''
import sympy as sy
import random as rand
from scipy import interpolate
'''

'''
Initiate Timer
'''
TimeStart = time()

'''
#User defined inputs
'''
TStep = (17.8E-13)
TFinal = (17.8E-10)
R0 = 0.02
V0X = 1E7
ParticleCount = 1 #No. of particles to generate energies for energy generation
BInput = 0.64 #Magnitude of B field near pole of magnet in experiment
ScaleV0Z = 1

'''
#Defining constants based on user input and nature (Cleared of all errors!)
'''
#Defining Space and Particle Density based on Pressure PV = NkT
k = 1.38E-23 #Boltzman Constant

#Natural Constants
Q_e = -1.602E-19 #Charge of electron
M_e = 9.11E-31 #Mass of electron
JToEv = 6.24E+18 #Joules to eV conversion
EpNaut = 8.854187E-12
u0 = 1.256E-6
k = 1/(4*np.pi*EpNaut)
QeMe = Q_e/M_e

'''
Create zeros matrices to populate later (Cannot create TimeIndex array!)
'''
TimeSpan = np.linspace(0,TFinal,num=round((TFinal/TStep)))
TimeIndex = np.linspace(0,TimeSpan.size,num=TimeSpan.size)
ParticleTrajectoryMat = np.zeros([91,TimeSpan.size,6])
BFieldTracking = np.zeros([TimeSpan.size,3])
InputAngle = np.array([np.linspace(0,90,91)])
OutputAngle = np.zeros([InputAngle.size,1])
OutputRadial = np.zeros([InputAngle.size,1])

'''
Define B-Field
'''
def BField(x,y,z):

    InputCoord = np.array([x,y,z])
    VolMag = 3.218E-6 #Volume of magnet in experiment in m^3
    BR = np.sqrt(InputCoord[0]**2 + InputCoord[1]**2 + InputCoord[2]**2)
    MagMoment = np.array([0,0,(BInput*VolMag)/u0])
    BDipole = (u0/(4*np.pi))*(((3*InputCoord*np.dot(MagMoment,InputCoord))/BR**5)-(MagMoment/BR**3))
    #BVec = np.array([BDipole[0],BDipole[1],BDipole[2]])
    #print(BDipole[0],BDipole[1],BDipole[2])
    return (BDipole[0],BDipole[1],BDipole[2])

'''
Lorentz Force Differential Equations Definition
'''
def LorentzForce(PosVel,t,Constants):

    X,Y,Z,VX,VY,VZ = PosVel
    Bx,By,Bz,QeMe = Constants
    BFInput = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])
    VelInput = np.array([VX,VY,VZ])
    Accel = QeMe * (np.cross(VelInput, BFInput))   
    LFEqs = np.concatenate((VelInput, Accel), axis = 0)
    return LFEqs

'''
Cartesean to Spherical coordinates converter function. Returns: [Radius (m), Theta (rad), Phi (rad)]
'''
def Cart2Sphere(xIn,yIn,zIn):
    P = np.sqrt(xIn**2 + yIn**2 + zIn**2)
    if xIn == 0:
        Theta = np.pi/2
    else:
        Theta = np.arctan(yIn/xIn)
    Phi = np.arccos(zIn/np.sqrt(xIn**2 + yIn**2 + zIn**2))
    SphereVector = np.array([P,Theta,Phi])
    return SphereVector

'''
Main Loop
'''
for angletrack in range(0,InputAngle.size):
    MirrorAngle = InputAngle[0,angletrack]
    MirrorAngleRad = MirrorAngle*(np.pi/180)
    V0Z = np.abs(V0X/np.sin(MirrorAngleRad))*np.sqrt(1-(np.sin(MirrorAngleRad))**2)
    V0Z = V0Z*ScaleV0Z
    #Define initial conditions
    V0 = np.array([[V0X,0,V0Z]])
    S0 = np.array([[0,R0,0]])
    ParticleTrajectoryMat[0,:] = np.concatenate((S0,V0),axis=None)
    for timeplace in range(0,TimeIndex.size-1):
        ICs = np.concatenate((S0,V0),axis=None)
        Bx,By,Bz = BField(S0[0,0],S0[0,1],S0[0,2])
        BFieldTracking[timeplace,:] = np.array([Bx,By,Bz])
        AllConstantInputs = [Bx,By,Bz,QeMe]
        t = np.array([TimeSpan[timeplace],TimeSpan[timeplace+1]])
        ODESolution = odeint(LorentzForce,ICs,t,args=(AllConstantInputs,))
        ParticleTrajectoryMat[angletrack,timeplace+1,:] = ODESolution[1,:]
        S0[0,0:3] = ODESolution[1,0:3]
        V0[0,0:3] = ODESolution[1,3:6]

    MatSize = np.array([ParticleTrajectoryMat.shape])
    RowNum = MatSize[0,1]
    SphereMat = np.zeros([RowNum,3])
    SphereMatDeg = np.zeros([RowNum,3])
    for cart2sphereplace in range(0,RowNum):
        SphereMat[cart2sphereplace,:] = Cart2Sphere(ParticleTrajectoryMat[angletrack,cart2sphereplace,0],ParticleTrajectoryMat[angletrack,cart2sphereplace,1],ParticleTrajectoryMat[angletrack,cart2sphereplace,2])

    for rad2deg in range(0,RowNum):
        SphereMatDeg[rad2deg,:] = np.array([SphereMat[rad2deg,0],(180/np.pi)*SphereMat[rad2deg,1],(180/np.pi)*SphereMat[rad2deg,2]])

    PhiDegVec = np.array([SphereMatDeg[:,2]])
    RVec = np.array([SphereMatDeg[:,0]])
    MinPhi = np.amin(PhiDegVec)
    MinPhiLocationTuple = np.where(PhiDegVec == np.amin(PhiDegVec))
    MinPhiLocation = int(MinPhiLocationTuple[1])
    RAtMinPhi = RVec[0,MinPhiLocation]
    OutputAngle[angletrack,0] = MinPhi
    OutputRadial[angletrack,0] = RAtMinPhi
    print('Mirror Angle Input (In deg): ',InputAngle[0,angletrack])
    print('Mirror Angle Output (In deg): ',MinPhi)
    print('R Value at minimum Phi (m): ',RAtMinPhi)

InputAngleTrans = np.matrix.transpose(InputAngle)
CompareMat = np.concatenate((InputAngleTrans,OutputAngle),axis=1)
```

Comment: By running your code in Spyder, I get kernel restarts. If I do it on the command line, I get a bunch of wanrnings about incorrect values, divide by 0, etc. I think that this contains errors that Spyder is still not able to handle correctly. The command line with IPython will allow you to debug it better, in my opinion.

Comment: I ran this in Jupyter and I did receive the "kernal died" message but without an explanation as to why this is happening. I also tried running this in the command window and received a "... is not recognized as an internal or external command for all lines"

Comment: You need to run it into a python shell for it to work. Depending on your system, I would suggest installing IPython. Google how to install it and use it on your system.